# How to initialize one field using another in case class?

Tags: scala, case-class

Suppose I have a case class like

```
case class Person(fname:String, lname:String, nickName:Option[String] = None)
```

On creating an instance like Person("John", "Doe"), I want nickName to be automatically assigned to fname, if one is not given. Eg:

```
val p1 = Person("John", "Doe")
p1.nickName.get == "John"

val p2 = Person("Jane", "Doe", "Joe")
p2.nickName.get == "Joe"
```

How can auto assignment of one field from another field be achieved?

Trying the solutions below in repl. I think this is something to do with repl

```
scala> case class Person(fname: String, lname:String, nickName:Option[String])
defined class Person

scala> object Person { def apply(fname:String, lname:String):Person = {Person(fname, lname, Some(fname))}}
  console:9: error: too many arguments for method apply: (fname: String, lname: String)Person in object Person
   object Person { def apply(fname:String, lname:String):Person = {Person(fname, lname, Some(fname))}}
```

Comment: see my answer's update for REPL thing (you shoud use :paste mode for companion object)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can overload the constructor of the case class

```
case class Foo(bar: Int, baz: Int) {
     def this(bar: Int) = this(bar, 0)
}
new Foo(1, 2)
new Foo(1)
```

So you can check the case if nickName is none.

You can also overload it's apply method in the same way. In that way, then you can use

```
Foo(1,2)
Foo(1)
```

Comment: I think you should re-word this into the context of the OP's example.

Answer (score 7):

## Technical Solution (don't)

On the current definition of case classes, you can override the constructor of the case class and the apply method of its companion object, as described in [the answer of Facundo Fabre](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28179438/1885392).

You will get something like this:

```
object Person {
  def apply(fname:String, lname:String): Person = Person(fname, lname, fname)
}

case class Person(fname:String, lname:String, nickName: String) {
  def this(fname:String, lname:String) = this(fname, lname, fname)
}
```

This is technical correct and quite clever coding. But for my taste its a little bit too clever, because it breaks an important property:

```
CaseClass.unapply(CaseClass.apply(x1,x2,x3)) == (x1,x2,x3)
```

In other words: When I construct a case class using `apply` with some tuple of parameter and then deconstruct it using `unapply` I expect to get the original tuple I put into `apply` (ignoring currying and option type).

But in this case, this property is not true any  more:

```
Person.unapply(Person("John", "Smith"))
// result: Option[(String, String, String)] = Some((John,Smith,John))
```

Deconstruction using `unapply` is used for pattern matching (`match{ case ... => ...`). And this is a common use case for case classes.

So while the code is quite clever, it might confuse other people and break properties their code relies on.

## Rephrase the problem (my suggestion)

When overly clever code is needed, it is often a good idea to rethink, what problem one tries to solve. In this case, I would suggest to distinguish between the nick name the user has chosen and a nick the system assigns to the user. In this case I would then just build a case class like this:

```
case class NickedPerson(fname : String, lname : String, chosenNick : Option[String] = None) {
  val nick = chosenNick.getOrElse(fname)
}
```

You can then just use the field `nick` to access the computed nick name, or use `chosenNick` if you want to know if the user has provided that nick name:

```
NickedPerson("John", "Smith").nick
// result: String = "John"
NickedPerson("John", "Smith", Some("Agent")).nick
// result: String = "Agent"
```

The basic properties about case classes are not changed by this code.

Answer (score 2):

Just explaining how to overload `apply` from companion object (in addition to @Facundo Fabre answer):

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

object Person {
   def apply(fname:String, lname:String): Person = Person(fname, lname, fname)
}
case class Person(fname:String, lname:String, nickName: String)


// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined object Person
defined class Person

scala> Person("aaa", "bbb")
res24: Person = Person(aaa,bbb,aaa)

scala> Person("aaa", "bbb", "ccc")
res25: Person = Person(aaa,bbb,ccc)
```

You could also define default value using muti-parameter list constructor, but it's hard to use such case class (no `toString` and pattern matching for last parameter), so won't recommend (but it's good if you want simmilar thing for methods):

```
scala> case class Person(fname:String, lname:String)(val nickName: String = fname)
defined class Person
```

Another funny solution (just to play), which I wouldn't recommend to use in real code:

```
scala> case class Person(fname:String, lname:String, var nickName: String = null){nickName = Option(nickName).getOrElse(fname)}
defined class Person

scala> Person("aaa", "bbb")
res32: Person = Person(aaa,bbb,aaa)
```